# How to match everything within a certain sequence in a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I want to be able to turn certain parts of a string to bold using a regular expression in PHP.
When the string contains text **surrounded by two asterisks**, it should turn bold.

I'm using three examples:

```
**The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.**

The **quick** brown fox **jumps over** the lazy dog.

**The quick* brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**.
```

I've tried:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\*\*(.+)\*\*/' , "<b>$1</b>" , $string);
```

Which fails on the second one because it gives:

```
The <b>quick** brown fox **jumps over</b> the lazy dog.
```

It should have stopped after quick and matched again at jumps.

I also tried:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/' , "<b>$1</b>" , $string);
```

Which works on the second one but fails on the third, matching nothing at all.

What I really want is something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\*\*([^*{2}]+)\*\*/' , "<b>$1</b>" , $string);
```

But I know that's know right. I think I should be using negative lookahead somehow but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The + modifier in your pattern needs to be ungreedy (see the ? after the +) ... otherwise it will gobble up everything it can up to the last occurrence of ** in the subject string.

```
$p = '{\*\*(.+?)\*\*}';
$r = '<bold>$1</bold>'
preg_replace($p, $r, $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `\*\*(.+?)\*\*`

You need to make the "match any character" portion non-greedy, otherwise it will go until it finds the last occurrence of `**`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/' , "<b>$1</b>" , $string);
```

The ? makes the capture lazy, meaning it will try and match the smallest bounded set of double asterisks.

For more information see here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You may already know this, but [php markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) already has this functionality, along with a whole host of other easy formatting stuff.